# TypeError using custom Python UDF in Spark 2.1

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pickle, user-defined-functions

I have a custom Python UDF that I register for use with a Spark dataframe.  The function is imported from other libraries and I'm packaging it up in a Python zip and including with py-files.  I'm running into a problem where the custom function appears to be interpreting a pickle object instead of the String I want it to.  Example code:

```
   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkTest").getOrCreate()
   df = spark.read.text(source_file)
   df.registerTempTable("test")

   testUDF = TaggerWrapper('en').word_tokenize
   tagger_udf  = udf(testUDF, StringType())

   df.withColumn("new_col", tagger_udf("value")).write.csv(path=path, mode='overwrite')
```

My executors return the error: TypeError: expected string argument.

When I create a custom function to return the type that's getting interpreted, I get this:

```
def get_type(s):
    return type(s)
```

u'net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor@566554e3'

When I do any other kind of simple UDF it works as expected returning something simple like "test" concatenated to each row in the data frame.

What is causing this?  Is my understanding correct?

Thanks!

A couple of updates...

I was able to get my UDF working.  One challenge is the file encoding.  The C++ bindings seem to be very picky about this.  My files were encoded as 8859.  I'm still struggling with Unicode but I was able to make ASCII work.

Comment: Which package is it from? is it treetaggerwrapper?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that.  It's a custom dependency with compiled C++ code for python bindings.

Answer (score 0):

A few reactions to this `UDF`

- if the package you use is not install on the nodes you have to import it using `--packages` but I'm not sure it works with C++ compiled packages

It seems the error is on the output though:

- Shouldn't `word_tokenize` return an array of strings (`ArrayType(StringType())`) instead of a string.
- If the type you return is a type that is not supported by `pyspark` it will issue an error saying it cannot be pickled (returning numpy ints for instance yields a similar error)

Finally:

- there is a word `tokenize` function in `spark.ml` that might do the trick for you https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#tokenizer

Comment: Hey Marie, thanks for the response.  Appreciate your help!  You are correct, the word_tokenize returns a list ultimately, so I tried changing it to an arraytype.  Unfortunately I got the same error, based on the stack trace I get it seems to be cause by the function call that the UDF references.  I'm also limited to using a custom library for this use case unfortunately.  It does actually import the library and attempts to execute the UDF.